# Excel autofill down using data from another sheet

Tags: excel, concatenation, autofill

I have two sheets, the first one containing my data and the second sheet I am concatenating the data from the first into a string. I would like to autofill down the rest of the cells on the second sheet, just like I could if the two columns were next to each other on the same sheet.

The problem is I have around 500,000 rows of data on the first sheet that need to be concatenated on the second sheet, and I would prefer to not drag my cursor down for 5 minutes straight.

Control + Shift + Down arrow doesn't work because there are many rows which are blank.

[image: Here is a visual example of what im doing]

Anyone have a solution? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Your mouse and press the Control key to highlight the portion you intended to fill then press Enter

Comment: This will not work because the CONCAT function will attempt to concatenate the 500,000 rows of data into one cell. You must use a LAMBDA helper function to iterate row by row.

Answer (score 0):

Several steps to set formulas all at once.

- activate `Sheet1`
- click a cell on any empty column, press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>down</kbd> goto last row
- press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>left</kbd> goto the first cell of last row
- press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>up</kbd> goto the last cell on column A (assuming it is `A501234`)
- acitvate `Sheet21`, input `A501234` on "cell reference box", press <kbd>Enter</kbd>
- hold <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd> press <kbd>up</kbd>, select A1:A501234
- hold <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> and click cell A1 to remove it from selection
- input formula `=CONCAT("I Love" & Sheet1!A501234)`, press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd> to set formulas on selection

*Note:* <kbd>down</kbd>  <kbd>up</kbd>  <kbd>left</kbd>  are arrow key.

[image: Cell Reference Box]

Answer (score 0):

Give a try to the following formula-

```
=MAP(Sheet1!A2:INDEX(Sheet1!A2:A500000,COUNTA(Sheet1!A2:A500000)),LAMBDA(x,CONCAT("Hello Excel ",x)))
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Formula to put on sheet 2:

```
=MAP( Sheet1!A2:A500001, LAMBDA(m, "I love " & m ))
```

[image]